# Only primary key tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to find tables having only primary key for my specified column. What I am trying is as follows:

```
SELECT   
    OBJECT_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName, 
    1 AS InsertPrimaryGuidOnly,
    0 AS InsertCustomerOnly, 
    0 AS InsertApplicationOnly, 
    0 AS InsertNoKeyOnly  
FROM 
    sys.indexes AS i 
INNER JOIN  
    sys.index_columns AS ic ON i.OBJECT_ID = ic.OBJECT_ID  
                            AND i.index_id = ic.index_id  
WHERE 
    i.is_primary_key = 1  
    AND COL_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID, ic.column_id) =  'CREDITCHECKGUID'    
    AND OBJECT_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID) NOT IN ('Customer', 'Application')
```

I am getting table list but it also lists down tables having column as primary and foreign key. What I want is only primary key tables. If the primary is also a foreign key, I don't want to list down that table. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Put this where clause in your query;

```
AND ic.OBJECT_ID NOT IN (select parent_object_id from sys.foreign_keys fk)
```

Complete query;

```
SELECT   
    ic.OBJECT_ID,
    OBJECT_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName, 
    1 AS InsertPrimaryGuidOnly,
    0 AS InsertCustomerOnly, 
    0 AS InsertApplicationOnly, 
    0 AS InsertNoKeyOnly  
FROM 
    sys.indexes AS i 
INNER JOIN  
    sys.index_columns AS ic ON i.OBJECT_ID = ic.OBJECT_ID  
                            AND i.index_id = ic.index_id  
WHERE 
    i.is_primary_key = 1  
    AND COL_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID, ic.column_id) =  'CREDITCHECKGUID'
    AND OBJECT_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID) NOT IN ('Customer', 'Application')
    AND ic.OBJECT_ID NOT IN (select parent_object_id from sys.foreign_keys fk)
```